# DataWarehouse for PowerBI Web

Tags: postgresql, powerbi, data-warehouse

People, I'm developing a DW for a set of internal information datamarts that i'm turning into a DWH.
In this moment, i'm using postgresql for this, but i'm open to try another tools/databases, like spark (STS), dremio, hive, etc.
What is my constraint here ?
The dataset and dashboard need to access the data stored in the database that is not in Azure and Azure for database, in this moment (for financial decisions), is not possible.

I've tried to access data with PowerBI Desktop on the PostgreSQL (hosted on another cloud provider), and that worked, but when i've published that, it required encryption that's available only in Azure PostgreSQL or i would need to use a gateway server to update the dataset in the PowerBI.
There is anyway to update the dataset without using a gateway on-premises server or Azure hosted services (SQL Database, Data Warehouse or Spark on Azure HDInsight) ?
The objective is to keep the actual cloud provider (as our applications and databases resides on that) and power the dashboards with good information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is anyway to update the dataset without using a gateway on-premises server or Azure hosted services

Not really.  That's what the [Power BI Gateway](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/gateway/) is for.

If you can't run a Gateway VM or a Database in Azure, you could push the data to Azure Storage and load into PowerBI from there.